# dbt project name retrieval in model sql file

Tags: dbt

I am new to dbt. I want to retrieve dbt project name in dbt model sql file.

Ex:

`SELECT '{{<project_name>}}'||'.'||'{{model.path}}' AS UPDATED_BY ;`

How can I pass <project_name> here. I dont want to create a variable in dbt_project.yml file to pass project name, instead I want the project name to be coming from dbt system variables.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to access the root project folder name.

In the **dbt_project.yml** file, there is a pre-populated `name` field that you can access using `"project_name"` in any dbt model.

```yaml
# dbt_project.yml 

name: your_project <--- This one

config-version: 2
version: version

profile: profilename
...
```

```
{{ log("Project Name: " ~ project_name, info=True) }}
```